# MongoDB bulk loading 36000 files

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoimport

I am newbie to mongoDB. Currently I have a dataframe with the full path to 36000 json files. I downloaded the mongoimport and placed it in my install bin directory. I would like to create a loop of some sort to load all files into my local install of mongodb. Should I do this in python or does the mongoimport have this feature that can be leveraged.

Comment: Personally, I would do it in Python for the sake of configuring error handling, among other things, but if you wanted to use `mongoimport`, you could do that too. Since it's just a cli, you could stick the `mongoimport` call in a bash loop (for example `for file in /path/to/jsonfiles/*; do`) and use `mongoimport` like you usually would.

Comment: I guess `mongoimport` should be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there maybe a better way to do this but since I already have all the file paths in a dataframe.

I generated a string like below

```
mongoimport --db DBNAME --collection NAME --file C:\some\path\file.json
```

Created for all 36000 files then I put it in a bat file and ran the bat file from the command line. This loaded all the files 1 by 1.

Comment: "Created for all 36000 files ..." - did you never hear something about "loop"?

Comment: Yea, but was 1am and I am just trying to get to the finish line. My python is a bit shaky. Beside i didnt know how I would execute the mongoimport within my python script. I used a loop to print full file path :)